# Get substring between two string

Tags: string, bash

I am making a script that returns system info. To get the CPU name I am using `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and I get the following output

```
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000037
cpu MHz         : 2299.853
cache size      : 46080 KB
physical id     : 0
```

How can I extract the model name? (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz)
Maybe there's a way to get text between model name\t: and stepping?

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to show their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, kindly edit your question by adding your efforts and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `grep` with `cut` could do it. Optionally adding `uniq` if there's more than one cpu

```
grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | cut -d: -f2 | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk, use colon as the field separator, test for the first field containing "model name" and print the second field:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /model name/ {print $2}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

sed can do it.

```
sed -n 's/model name[ \t]*: //p' /proc/cpuinfo
```

You should be aware that you will probably get multiple lines, and they might not all be the same.

You should also be aware it isn't always "model name".  Several of my older boxes have "Processor".

So perhaps:

```
sed -n 's/\(model name\|Processor\)[ \t]*: //p' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it completely in bash, cutting at the strings, consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="$( cat /proc/cpuinfo )"

b="${a//$'\n'/ }"
b="${b//$'\t'/ }"

b="${b#*model name : }"
b="${b%%stepping *}"

echo "$b"
```

`${b#*text}` removes the shortest prefix matching "`*text`" from b.
`${b%%text*}` removes the longest suffix matching "`text*`" from b.
Since "*" doesn't seem to work across lines, I first reduced newlines and tabs to spaces.

(I figured a direct answer for bash scripting was appropriate.)